# How to prevent decimal truncation in Word 2003 with Web Service auto population

Tags: web-services, vbscript, word-2003

I have a document template which is being auto populated via an external web service. The incoming data exists as a currency (e.g. 3.10) but when it is passed into the Word Document template the variable is truncated to remove any trailing 0's. I need the number to always appear with 2 decimals, even if they are both 0's.

This is with the 2003 version of Word, I have not tested with other versions since all of our document templates need to be generated using that version of Word.

I feel like this can be done with a Macro or a VB script but I have a very small amount of time & no experience with these tools - Any help is greatly appreciated!